# Using Comparison Operators in preprocessor directives C++

Tags: c++, arduino, c-preprocessor, directive, comparison-operators

I want to define some functions based on a constant value:

```
#define mode 5

#if mode & 2 != 0
  // function 1
#endif

#if mode & 4 != 0
  // function 2
#endif
```

This may sound and look weird but I want to use one constant to define and activate some program modules.
defining `mode = 2` includes function 1, `mode = 4` includes function 2 and `mode = 6` includes both functions.
There is one problem: Comparison Operators like `==`, `!=`, `>` or `<` doesn't seem to work in directives and `#if` statements are always executed.

What am I doing wrong? Am I trying to do a stupid or impossible thing?

Comment: *"doesn't seem to work in directives and are simply ignored"* - It's not clear what you mean here. In general "doesn't work" is not a useful problem statement. Please amend your [mre] to demonstrate exactly what the problem is. If there's an error, copy it verbatim. If it runs but does the wrong thing, say what you expect, as well as what happens in practice.

Comment: `mode & 2 != 0` is not `(mode & 2) != 0`

Comment: In such a situation, to avoid problems, i prefer to use `constexpr int mode = 5;` etc.

Comment: FWIW, another approach that doesn't use the preprocessor is to use a template like `template <int N> void my_function_set(...);` and then specialize it for the different values of `N` and then you would just have `my_function_set<constant>(...)` at the call site.

Comment: @Damien - You can use `constexpr`, but then you have the problem of it being entirely useless in conditional compilation. C++ may have reduced the need for the preprocessor substantially, but it hasn't replaces all of its uses (yet).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I had expected that after compilation optimisation, the generated code would have been cleaned up. But I did not check it carefully effectively. A little bit disappointing.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica It's not entirely useless since `if constexpr` exists and can be used to conditionally compile/omit branches within functions, but sure, that only goes so far and there's no way to omit declarations at block scope, class members, etc.

Comment: @underscore_d - `if constexpr` can only be used in templates, has to be dependent itself, and won't permit you to call an entirely non-existent function if the call is not a dependent call. Simply put, it doesn't allow "token soup" like is sometimes required for supporting cross platform code in all cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&` has lower [precendence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) then `!=`. So:

```
MODE & 2 != 0
```

is the same as

```
MODE & (2 != 0)
```

The `2 != 0` is logically true, so the result of `!=` operator is a `1`. Thus this is the same as

```
MODE & 1
```

It's just checking the first bit. While you want:

```
(MODE & 2) != 0
```

To check if the second bit is set. But really just remove the `!=` part and do:

```
#if MODE & 2
```

Remember to [prefer upper case names for macro names](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Macro_Names).

> This may sound and look weird

No, that sounds completely normal. I would go with a lot more descriptive names, then plain `& 2` - [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) are confusing. Like:

```
#define MODE  (MODE_ENABLE_FUNC_1 | MODE_ENABLE_FUNC_2)

#define MODE_ENABLE_FUNC_1  (1<<0)
#define MODE_ENABLE_FUNC_2  (1<<1)
#define MODE_ENABLE_FUNC_3  (1<<2)
#define MODE_IS_ENABLED(mode, feature) ( ((mode) & (feature)) != 0)
#if MODE_IS_ENABLED(MODE, MODE_ENABLE_FUNC_1)
// etc.
```

If possible, prefer to use C++ templates and SFINAE, rather then plain C macros.

> What am I doing wrong?

You are assuming that `!=` has lower precedence then `&`.

> Am I trying to do a stupid or impossible thing?

No.

---

I remember the part [*The development of C language* by Dennis M. Ritchie](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) and from section name `Neonatal C` he writes:

> [...] In converting from B to C, one wants to replace & by && in such a statement; to make the conversion less painful, we decided to keep the precedence of the & operator the same relative to ==, and merely split the precedence of && slightly from &. Today, it seems that it would have been preferable to move the
> relative precedences of & and ==, and thereby simplify a common C
> idiom: to test a masked value against another value, one must write
>
> ```
> if ((a&mask) == b) ...
> ```
>
> where the inner parentheses are required but easily forgotten.

No worries - you are not the first and not the last to forget about the braces in `&` and another operator context.

Comment: *Higher* precedence would make things associate as expected. This answer needs s/higher/lower/g

Comment: I do not understand - what's the point of the edit? `#if mode1 != 0` expands to `#if mode & 2 != 0` which is still the same code. Macros are not evaluated when defined, but are evaluated _after_ all replacements - there's no difference. Still, you can `#if (mode1) != 0` if you want or `#define mode1 (mode & 2)` (or both..)

Comment: Operator `!=` is working. I do not understand what you narrowed - as explained, `mode & 2 != 0` [is checking the first bit](https://godbolt.org/z/W36rva). You presented same code, only with another macro - there's no difference. As mentioned, macros are _not evaluated_ when defined. Research [macro pitfalls](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/project/rhel-doc/3/rhel-cpp-en-3/macro-pitfalls.html) with operator precedence contexts.

Comment: My mistake. My first language is not English and I misunderstood you.
Sorry and thanks for this great answer.